# welcome message, "send" sometimes comes up as undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this welcome message my bot sends when someone joins my server, it works 90% of the time but it crashes the bot at random times, any help would be much appreciated!

```
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('694107369436741702');
    const memberCount = guild.memberCount;

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#8397A7')
        .setTitle(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to Radiant Community!`)
        .setDescription(`Welcome to **Radiant Community!** :hugging: We hope you enjoy your stay and make sure to read <#694124118487990362>  before chatting anywhere, and remember to get your self the role you want to get updates from in <#707274437896175676>  otherwise you might not be notified of updates and announcements! :wink: You are our **${memberCount}th** member! :tada:`)

    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('801321793129414676').send(embed)
});
```

Comment: Could you please show the full error? Are you sure it's not "cannot read property send of undefined" instead of "send is not defined"?

Comment: To add to @Lioness100's speculation, most likely the cached guild is undefined, due to the guild not being cached.

Comment: Hello! This is as much as i can type of the error:
` /home/container/bot3/index.js:84
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('801321793129414676').send(embed)
                                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/bot3/index.js:84:63)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_ADD] (/home/container/bot3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_MEMBER_ADD.js:16:14)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket`

Answer (score 0):

It might not be in the cache so you should await it first and then try calling send on it.

```js
let gMember = await guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('801321793129414676');
gMember.send(embed);
```